# Change ImGui Button name when click it

Tags: imgui

Is it possible to change the button name when you click it?

I'm currently doing a imgui project. I want to change the `Global` view and the `Local` view in one button using `ImGui::Button`. Is that possible in the current ImGui version right now?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the label of the button depending on your current state..
And you can use the ### operator (described in FAQ) to keep a stable ID.

```
if (ImGui::Button(view_is_local ? "Local###ViewMode" : "Global###ViewMode"))
    view_is_local = !view_is_local;
```